# Connect to ftps:// URL

Tags: c#, ssl, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftps

I am trying to use this code to upload a file to an FTP, the problem I have is that when the syntax hits the `serverURI.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp` it returns false.  Does that mean I have my URI address set-up incorrectly?  I know it is a valid address, I have used ftptest.net to verify the site is up and running.  What is incorrect in my syntax?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Uri serverUri = new Uri("ftps://afjafaj.org");
  string userName = "Ricard";
  string password = "";
  string filename = "C:\\Book1.xlsx";
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AcceptAllCertificatePolicy;
  UploadFile(serverUri, userName, password, filename);
}

public bool AcceptAllCertificatePolicy(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
  return true;
}

public bool UploadFile(Uri serverUri, string userName, string password, string fileName)
{
  if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
    return false;

  try
  {
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
    request.EnableSsl = true;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fileName);
    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
    sourceStream.Close();
    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("Response status: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    throw exc;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `ftps://` prefix is not a [standard IANA URI scheme](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml). There's only `ftp://` scheme, as defined by [RFC 1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-3).

Anyway, the `ftps://` is still recognized by some software to refer to an FTP over TLS/SSL protocol (secure FTP). This mimics `https://` scheme, which is an HTTP over TLS/SSL (`https://` is a standard scheme).

Though the `ftps://` is NOT recognized by the .NET framework.

To connect to the *explicit* mode FTP over TLS/SSL, change your URI to `ftp://`, and set [`FtpWebRequest.EnableSsl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.enablessl) to `true` (what you are doing already).

---

Note that the `ftps://` prefix commonly refers to an *implicit* mode FTP over TLS/SSL. The .NET framework supports only an *explicit* mode. Though even if your URI is indeed referring to the *implicit* mode, most servers would support the *explicit* mode too anyway. So this won't be a problem typically. For the *explicit* mode, `ftpes://` is sometimes used. See my article to understand the difference between [FTP over TLS/SSL implicit and explicit modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftps#methods).