# powershell FTPS csv file

Tags: powershell, ssl, ftp

I am trying to upload a csv file via FTPS as I need SSL enabled but this code keeps throwing an error message (particularly at line `$rs = $ftp.GetRequestStream()`):

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$Url = "ftp://hosturl"
$filename = "somefile.csv"
$usessl=$true

try {
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($url)
    $ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($uri)
    $ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$ftp
    $ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
    $ftp.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
    $ftp.UseBinary = $true
    $ftp.UsePassive = $true
    $ftp.EnableSsl = $usessl
    $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filename)
    $ftp.ContentLength = $content.Length
    $rs = $ftp.GetRequestStream()
    $rs.Write($content, 0, $content.Length)
    'File Uploaded.'
    $rs.Close()
    $rs.Dispose()
}
catch{
    Throw $_    
}
```

Error Message:

```
Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "System error."
```

Comment: [Log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56220620/850848) please.

Comment: are you sure about $url? should'nt it be: "ftps://...."

Comment: @JonathanMULLER No, .NET framework does not recognize `ftps://` protocol in URLs. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30082054/850848

Comment: maybe have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606809/powershell-ftps-upload-to-box-com-using-passive-mode

Comment: @JonathanMULLER Good find. Seeing that the proposed answer actually does not do anything special, I guess that the probem is that OP (both here and there) try to read whole file to memory and the file may be too large for that. If that's the case, I suggest that the `CopyTo` (*"Advanced options"*) solution from my answer to [Upload files with FTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867385/850848#46582183) might be a less obscure solution.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yeah indeed. nothing fancy. I will check out later also, I am quite curious why it epic fails.

Comment: I've improved the question found by @Bhaal22 and I have posted a (hopefully comprehensive) answer there. I'm closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: cool @MartinPrikryl.